# Если создать свой мессенджер, обязательно ли передавать переписки роскомнадзору?

Tags: соцсети, юридические-аспекты

я хотел попробовать создать приложение по типу мессенджера, но наткнулся на статью, в которой написано что нужно передавать все переписки властям. В интернете больше почти ничего про это не нашёл, поэтому спрашиваю здесь.

Comment: А это вы спрашивайте у юриста, а не у нас. Если мы дадим вам неправильный совет, и вы ему последуете, то в тюрьму сесть придётся вам, а не нам.

Comment: Рано или поздно придётся, да. Когда достаточно вырастете и до вас будет кому-то дело.

Comment: На начальном этапе не придётся. Ваши переписки передавать властям будут провайдеры, через которых вы будете передавать сообщения

Comment: @Darth Кстати, да. Забыл я про СОРМ-2 с DPI

Comment: @Darth, https же?

Comment: @Qwertiy сама переписка не так важна. важно найти всех связанных людей.

Comment: @Qwertiy https гарантирует, что прочитать трафик сможет только товарищ майор, у которого для этого есть подписанный сертификат, а всяким другим злоумышленникам придется помучиться. И то не на 100%.

Comment: @Darth, а откуда у него сертификат?

Comment: @Qwertiy попросят у сервис провайдера sslkeylog

Comment: Где то читал, что при создании ресурса в интернет и набора (точно не помню) определенного кол-ва пользователей, нужно регистрироваться. Естественно при регистрации вы передадите им право на мониторинг контента, удаление по их запросу информации и т.д. :) Но это читал давно, может что и поменялось. А трафик они уже давно мониторят от всех провайдеров.

Comment: @FrancNet это для блогов и пабликов - регистрироваться в Роскомнадзоре как СМИ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мессенжеры  отнесены на основании закона от 27.07.2006 № 149-ФЗ к организаторам распространения информации в сети "Интернет" (ОРИ). Лицензии на это не требуется.

Переписки предоставлять не нужно. роскомнадзор занимается не этим.

с роскомнадзором будет вас контролировать:

- если обрабатываете персональные данные пользователей неправильно.
- если вас приравняют к средствам массовой информации

переписками и прослушками занимается ФСБ

- если вас приравняют к оператору связи

Но есть момент, что пользователя нужно идентифицировать - нельзя создавать анонимные месенжеры. при идентификации вы получите немного персональных данных - их нужно правильно хранить: на территории России и защитить от утечек.

прочитайте эти 93 листа, вроде то

http://pravo.gov.ru/proxy/ips/?docbody&nd=102108264